# How do I find out what URI to pass with my intent to another Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What I'm after is this: we're using a 3rd party wifi-connected scanner on a tablet. I am now tasked to develop an app that will take the scanned image and perform certain operations on it. There is an associated 3rd party app for the scanner that manages the connection to the scanner as well as allowing one to scan, etc.

So now what I need to do is create an intent that tells this app to start scanning and send me the images, or the path to the images.

One starts an "external" app like such:

```
Intent myintent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
```

What I need to know is how to figure out the proper URI format. The app doesn't have any relevant documentation. Do I send it the camera URI, but make it pop up an app picker where the user can select the scanning app? Or is there a way to ask the app programmatically what it expects its URI to look like?

Comment: `I hope the title is clear`. Please do not refer to your title. Put all info in the body of your post.

Comment: Contact the manufacturer of the scanner and **ask them**. Nobody else on the planet will be able to help you. "Or is there a way to ask the app programmatically what it expects its URI to look like?" -- no.

Comment: I've been waiting 2 weeks for the manufacturer to get back to me.

Comment: You can install [intentintercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) which hooks into the android intent system and let you see most of the intents